# Visual studio 2012 gives me error "The C# project is targeting ,net framework, Version=v4.6, which is not installed on this machine"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-framework-version, .net-4.6

I had a .net 4.6 project and I installed the .Net Framework 4.6 but when I open my project Visual studio 2012 gives me those 3 options

> 1-Change the target to .Net Framework 4.6. You can change back to
>   ".Net Framework, Version=v4.6" at later time.
>
> 2-Download ".NetFramework, Version=v4.6". The project will not change.
>
> 3-Do not load the project.

I'm sure that I had .Net 4.6 installed on my computer

Answer (score 1):

The Idea that Visual studio 2012 doesn't support by default building project using .Net 4.6 and you have to setup something called `targeting .net framework` this allows you to find .Net 4.6 as a target .Net version on the project properties.

To update you studio 2012 you have to download 12.9 MB [update from this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48136)